# Not able to find ~/.ivy2/.credentials file in my Macbook

Tags: macos, file, search, credentials

for the setup for my project, I want to edit ~/.ivy2/.credentials file but I am not able to find it on my mac.

I tried to find it by running this command on my terminal and by using spotlight search but I didn't find anything. Can someone please share the step-by-step guide to find this file on mac as I didn't find anything related to this on StackOverflow or any other platform?

Answer (score 0):

Use command "cmd+shift+." in macbook to see the hidden folders in your project folder. If the required folder is not available you can create one.